# Why does high frequency decoupling require a small capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, decoupling-capacitor, decoupling, esr

Why can't a large ceramic capacitor with low ESR feed at high frequency? Maybe becase of resonance, since the higher freqeuency resonance can be achieved by lower C and ESL both not only equivalent series inductance (ESL.)

Could we use a small capacitor  with a transistor capacitor multiplier to  take advantage of higher capacitor and small capacitor together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really is about ESL.

While increasing capacitance brings down the impedance, larger capacitances come in larger packages which have larger ESL.

The capacitors with small physical package have less ESL.

So depending on what impedance you need at high frequency, an 1 nF capacitor in small package is better than 1nF capacitor in large package.

So is not about resonance itself, but smaller ESL will move the resonance peak to higher frequency.

Using a capacitance multiplier can make sense at mains frequency supplies, but it is basically just a transistor and capacitor used as a regulator to reduce ripple so it would not work beyond the bandwidth of the transistor anyway. For regulators and chip supply bypassing it really is best to have the bypass caps where they are needed to have the required energy available as fast as it is needed and when it is needed.

That is why smallest physical and smallest capacitance value capacitors are right near the chip so for quick surges of current the energy is quickly available with low ripple, but they can't provide much energy for slower speeds or long durations. The larger caps with larger ESL can be further away as they can provide energy for slower speends for longer durations.

Comment: Mains frequency supplies means 50/60Hz?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd Yes, that's what Justme meant. Anyway a capacitance multiplier is good only for frequencies that are much less than the BJT cutoff frequency. That's good for signals with low harmonic content, like ripple from a rectified and filtered mains waveform. Any signal with substantial harmonic content, such as signals with sharp edges, won't be filtered too much by the multiplier (the higher harmonics will pass unscathed).